# How to combine two LINQ Expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have the following LINQ query in c#

```
var stats = from s in context.Stats                                                                                                  
        select s;

Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> e1 = s => s.Age >= 15 && s.Age < 25;
Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> e2 = s => s.Age >= 40 && s.Age < 50;

stats = stats.Where(e1);
```

This code works and gives me the rows from the Stats table where Age is between 15 an 25.

Now, i would like to get the rows from 15 to 25 AND from 40 to 50.

How do I combine those 2 expressions ?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit ugly but if you want to keep them as expressions:

```
stats = stats.Where(s => (e1.Compile()(s) || e2.Compile()(s))).ToList();
```

If you can change them to `Func`s it's cleaner:

```
Func<Stat, bool> e1 = s => s.Age >= 15 && s.Age < 25;
Func<Stat, bool> e2 = s => s.Age >= 40 && s.Age < 50;

stats = stats.Where(s => e1(s) || e2(s)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

How about...

```
Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> e1 = s => 
   (s.Age >= 15 && s.Age < 25) || (s.Age >= 40 && s.Age < 50);
```

Comment: Hum, that works. 
But I would like to do something like that :
    stats.Where(e1 || e2)
but no success

Comment: @stephone In that case I like juharr's solution the best `stats = stats.Where(e1).Union(stats.Where(e2));`

Comment: That solution returns all table rows

Answer (score 1):

You could do a Union like this

```
stats = stats.Where(e1).Union(stats.Where(e2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> GetOrExpression(
    Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> e1,
    Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> e2)
{
    return s => e1.Compile()(s) || e2.Compile()(s);
}

Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> e1 = s => s.Age >= 15 && s.Age < 25;
Expression<Func<Stat, bool>> e2 = s => s.Age >= 40 && s.Age < 50;

stats = stats.Where(GetOrExpression(e1, e2));
```

Comment: since e1/e2 are expressions you will need to do `e1.Compile(s) || e2.Compile(s)`